# Solr/Lucene highlighted keywords - paddings

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, solr, highlighting

1. I would like a specific padding (EG '...')  --> **only** on start/end of fragments that are **truncated**,
2. I would also like to concatenate 2 fragments, even if they are not close, like:

... fragment1 ... fragment2 ...

Are there any fragmenters / highlight settings that can be used?

Answer (score 0):

i hope i understood your question correctly.

check out the [HighlightingParameters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters)

you have a lot of options there.

you can also specify your own hl.simple.pre/hl.simple.post. then you can parse the output every way you like.

it is also quite common to give a span tag with a custom css class, that you can style.